# Use javers query without entity classes in another project

Tags: javers

i got two projects. In the first one are entities, which changes i save with javes. then i got a second project, where i want to test if the first project saves the changes correctly. but the second one has no dependency to the entities of the first one. is ist possible  in the second project to query for changes of the entities of the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible since JaVers needs to know how to deserialize object snapshots. Snapshots doesn't capture property types. Original classes are used as the 'property source' (list of current properties with their types).